# How can I download a very large list of URLs so that the downloaded files are split into subfolders containing the first letter of the filenames?

Tags: wget, download

I want to download many files (> tens of millions). I have the URL for each file. I have the list of URLs in a file `URLs.txt`:

```
http://mydomain.com/0wd.pdf
http://mydomain.com/asz.pdf
http://mydomain.com/axz.pdf
http://mydomain.com/b00.pdf
http://mydomain.com/bb0.pdf
etc.
```

I can download them via `wget -i URLs.txt`, however it would go over the [maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466596/395857) number of files that can be placed in one folder.

How can I download this large list of URLs so that the downloaded files are split into subfolders containing the first letter of the filenames? E.g.,:

```
0/0wd.pdf
a/asz.pdf
a/axz.pdf
b/b00.pdf
b/bb0.pdf
etc.
```

If that matters, I use Ubuntu.

Comment: I would split the URLs.txt file into multiple files (URLs-0.txt, URLs-a.txt, ...) and then loop over them doing `wget -i` on each  in the appropriate subdirectory.

Comment: Take [SHA](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.sha3_224) of the URL. Pick off a couple of prefix nybbles, and use that as the directory name.

Comment: You might do a frequency count on the output of whatever algorithm you choose. If the results are badly skewed, you might still have a mix of too-large and small directories. I assume the names shown are not real: an alphabet of A-Za-z0-9 of length 3 has less than 250,000 unique names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
awk -F/ '{print substr($NF, 1, 1), $0}' urls.txt |
  xargs -L1 bash -c 'mkdir -p -- "$0" && curl -sSF -O --output-dir "$0" "$1"'
```

The `awk` prefixes each line with the first character of the filename, which is then used to select an output directory in the `curl` command. You could use the `-P` option to the GNU implementation of `xargs` to run multiple fetches in parallel.

That assumes URLs don't contain whitespace, quotes or backslashes but URLs should not contain those other than URI-encoded (even if `curl` is able to cope with them and do the URI-encoding by itself).

Given your sample input, running the above produces:

```
.
├── 0
│   └── 0wd.pdf
├── a
│   ├── asz.pdf
│   └── axz.pdf
└── b
    ├── b00.pdf
    └── bb0.pdf
```

Answer (score -1):

ChatGPT gave some working code in Python (I confirm that it works with Python 3.11):

> ```
> import os import requests
>
> def download_files_with_subfolders(url_file):
>     with open(url_file, 'r') as file:
>         for url in file:
>             url = url.strip()
>             filename = os.path.basename(url)
>             first_letter = filename[0]
>
>             # Create subfolder if it doesn't exist
>             subfolder = os.path.join(first_letter, '')
>             os.makedirs(subfolder, exist_ok=True)
>
>             # Download the file
>             response = requests.get(url)
>             if response.status_code == 200:
>                 file_path = os.path.join(subfolder, filename)
>                 with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
>                     file.write(response.content)
>                 print(f"Downloaded: {url} -> {file_path}")
>             else:
>                 print(f"Failed to download: {url} (Status code: {response.status_code})")
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     urls_file = "somefile.txt"
>     download_files_with_subfolders(urls_file)
> ```

with `somefile.txt` containing:

```
http://mydomain.com/0wd.pdf
http://mydomain.com/asz.pdf
http://mydomain.com/axz.pdf
http://mydomain.com/b00.pdf
http://mydomain.com/bb0.pdf
etc.
```

---

More advanced variants:

1. Keep the last modified date from the response headers (the code is also mostly from ChatGPT):

```
import requests
import os
from datetime import datetime

def download_file(url, local_filename):
    # Send a GET request to the server
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Get the last modified date from the response headers
        last_modified_header = response.headers.get('Last-Modified')
        last_modified_date = datetime.strptime(last_modified_header, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')

        # Save the content to a local file while preserving the original date
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
                f.write(chunk)

        # Set the local file's last modified date to match the original date
        os.utime(local_filename, (last_modified_date.timestamp(), last_modified_date.timestamp()))

        print(f"Downloaded {local_filename} with the original date {last_modified_date}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to download file. Status code: {response.status_code}")


def download_files_with_subfolders(url_file):
    with open(url_file, 'r') as file:
        for url in file:
            url = url.strip()
            filename = os.path.basename(url)
            first_letter = filename[0]

            # Create subfolder if it doesn't exist
            subfolder = os.path.join(first_letter, '')
            os.makedirs(subfolder, exist_ok=True)

            file_path = os.path.join(subfolder, filename)
            download_file(url, file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls_file = "somefile.txt"
    download_files_with_subfolders(urls_file)
```

2. Multithreaded download:

```
import requests
import os
from datetime import datetime

from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def download_file(url, local_filename):
    # Send a GET request to the server
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Get the last modified date from the response headers
        last_modified_header = response.headers.get('Last-Modified')
        last_modified_date = datetime.strptime(last_modified_header, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')

        # Save the content to a local file while preserving the original date
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
                f.write(chunk)

        # Set the local file's last modified date to match the original date
        os.utime(local_filename, (last_modified_date.timestamp(), last_modified_date.timestamp()))

        print(f"Downloaded {local_filename} with the original date {last_modified_date}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to download file. Status code: {response.status_code}")


def download_files_with_subfolders(url_file, num_threads=4):
    download_arguments = []
    with open(url_file, 'r') as file:
        for url in file:
            url = url.strip()
            filename = os.path.basename(url)
            first_letter = filename[0]

            # Create subfolder if it doesn't exist
            subfolder = os.path.join(first_letter, '')
            os.makedirs(subfolder, exist_ok=True)

            file_path = os.path.join(subfolder, filename)
            download_arguments.append((url, file_path))

    pool = ThreadPool(num_threads)
    results = pool.starmap(download_file, download_arguments)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls_file = "somefile.txt"
    download_files_with_subfolders(urls_file, num_threads=10)
```

3. Make one folder for the first letter, and a subfolder for the second letter. E.g.,:

```
0/w/0wd.pdf
a/s/asz.pdf
a/x/axz.pdf
b/0/b00.pdf
b/b/bb0.pdf
etc.
```

Code:

```
import requests
import os
from datetime import datetime

from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def download_file(url, local_filename):
    # Send a GET request to the server
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Get the last modified date from the response headers
        last_modified_header = response.headers.get('Last-Modified')
        last_modified_date = datetime.strptime(last_modified_header, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')

        # Save the content to a local file while preserving the original date
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
                f.write(chunk)

        # Set the local file's last modified date to match the original date
        os.utime(local_filename, (last_modified_date.timestamp(), last_modified_date.timestamp()))

        print(f"Downloaded {local_filename} with the original date {last_modified_date}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to download file. Status code: {response.status_code}")


def download_files_with_subfolders(url_file, num_threads=4):
    download_arguments = []
    with open(url_file, 'r') as file:
        for url in file:
            url = url.strip()
            filename = os.path.basename(url)
            first_letter = filename[0]
            second_letter = filename[1]

            # Create subfolder if it doesn't exist
            subfolder = os.path.join(first_letter, '')
            os.makedirs(subfolder, exist_ok=True)
            subsubfolder = os.path.join(first_letter, second_letter)
            os.makedirs(subsubfolder, exist_ok=True)

            file_path = os.path.join(subsubfolder, filename)
            download_arguments.append((url, file_path))

    pool = ThreadPool(num_threads)
    results = pool.starmap(download_file, download_arguments)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls_file = "somefile.txt"
    download_files_with_subfolders(urls_file, num_threads=10)
```